# Sorting into arrays based on radio button choices giving mixed results

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays

I have two `radio` button groups:

1. For `attendance` and have values of "yes" and "no"
2. For `dietary` choice and has the values of "Vegetarian / Vegan" and "Non-vegetarian"

The fields for `dietary` only show if the user has selected "yes" for attendance.

I'm sorting those who have accepted, declined, chose veg or non-veg into their own arrays (so 4 arrays exist). The values for these 4 arrays are passed onto a hidden field which is then posted to DB.

I have successfully managed to sort who has accepted or declined into their own arrays. However, since I've added another `change` function to sort the diet options also, I get mixed results. Steps to recreate in the demo:

1. For "John", click yes for attendance
2. John is added to the `attending list` (console log)
3. For "John", click "Non-vegetarian"
4. John is added to the `non veg list`
5. For Alex, click yes for attendance
6. Alex is added to the `attending list` alongside John
7. For Alex, click "Vegetarian / Vegan"
8. Alex is added to the "veg list", but John is removed from the "Non veg list"

Also, if a user clicks yes to attendance initially, then selects a diet option and then clicks "no" to attendance after, their name from the diet arrays should be removed (since they're not attending). I've tried to address this with `if ( attendance_radio.val() == "yes" ) { }` but no luck.

Demo below:

```js
(function ($) {
  var attendance_radio = $(".input-radio-attendance");
  var diet_radio = $(".input-radio-diet");

  var accepted_array = [];
  var declined_array = [];

  var veg_array = [];
  var nonveg_array = [];

  /* sort accepted and declined into arrays */
  attendance_radio.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();

    if (checkedVal == "yes") {
      accepted_array.push(name);
      declined_array.splice($.inArray(name, declined_array), 1);
    } 
    else {
      declined_array.push(name);
      accepted_array.splice($.inArray(name, accepted_array), 1);
    }

    var accepted_list = accepted_array.join(",");
    var declined_list = declined_array.join(",");

    console.log("attending list: " + accepted_list);
    console.log("declined list: " + declined_list);
  });

  /* get count of veg and non veg numbers */
  diet_radio.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();
  
    // only add to array if user is attending
    if ( attendance_radio.val() == "yes" ) {
      if (checkedVal == "veg") {
        veg_array.push(name);
        nonveg_array.splice($.inArray(name, nonveg_array), 1);
      } 
      else {
        nonveg_array.push(name);
        veg_array.splice($.inArray(name, veg_array), 1);
      }
    }
  
    var veg_list = veg_array.join(",");
    var nonveg_list = nonveg_array.join(",");
  
    console.log("veg list: " + veg_list);
    console.log("non veg list: " + nonveg_list);
  });

  /* showing dietary fields if yes is selected */
  attendance_radio.each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var checkedVal = $this.val();

      if( checkedVal == "yes" ) {
        $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").addClass("d-flex");
        diet_radio.prop('required',true);
      } 
      else {
        $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").removeClass("d-flex");
        diet_radio.prop('required',false);
      }
    });
  });
}) (jQuery);
```

```css
.group,
.group__inner{
  display: flex;
}

.group{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dietary{
  display: none;
}

.attendance{
  display: flex;
}

.d-flex{
  display: flex;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="group">

  <!------------->
  <!-- guest 1 -->
  <!------------->

  <div class="guest">
    <span class="guest__name">John</span>
    
    <div class="guest__options">
      <!-- attendace -->
      <div class="attendance">
        <span>Attending?</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-yes-0" type="radio" name="attendance-0" value="yes" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-no-0" type="radio" name="attendance-0" value="no" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="attending-no-0">No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- show dietary options when attendace is yes -->
      <div class="dietary">
        <span>Dietary preference</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-veg-0" type="radio" name="diet-0" value="veg" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="diet-veg-0">Vegetarian / Vegan</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-nonveg-0" type="radio" name="diet-0" value="nonveg" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="diet-nonveg-0">Non-vegetarian</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!------------->
  <!-- guest 2 -->
  <!------------->

  <div class="guest">
    <span class="guest__name">Alex</span>
    
    <div class="guest__options">
      <!-- attendace -->
      <div class="attendance">
        <span>Attending?</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-yes-1" type="radio" name="attendance-1" value="yes" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-no-1" type="radio" name="attendance-1" value="no" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="attending-no-1">No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- show dietary options when attendace is yes -->
      <div class="dietary">
        <span>Dietary preference</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-veg-1" type="radio" name="diet-1" value="veg" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="diet-veg-1">Vegetarian / Vegan</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-nonveg-1" type="radio" name="diet-1" value="nonveg" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="diet-nonveg-1">Non-vegetarian</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Also tried

```js
  diet_radio.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();

    // only add to diet arrays if user is attending
    if ( $(this).closest(".guest").find(".input-radio-attendance:checked").val() == "yes" ) {
      if (checkedVal == "veg") {
        veg_array.push(name);
        nonveg_array.splice($.inArray(name, nonveg_array), 1);
      } else {
        nonveg_array.push(name);
        veg_array.splice($.inArray(name, veg_array), 1);
      }
    }

    // if user selects yes to attendance, then selects a diet option, then changes atendance to no, remove them from diet arrays
    if( accepted_list.includes(name) ){
      veg_array.splice( $.inArray(name, veg_array), 1 );
      nonveg_array.splice( $.inArray(name, nonveg_array), 1 );
    }

    var veg_list = veg_array.join(",");
    var nonveg_list = nonveg_array.join(",");

    veg_field.val(veg_list);
    nonveg_field.val(nonveg_list);

    console.log("veg list: " + veg_list);
    console.log("non veg list: " + nonveg_list);

  });
```

### Edit @Lajos Arpad

[image]

### Edit 2 @Lajos Arpad

Still seeing a bug where user isn't removed from list after declining when initially choosing there diet option.

For ease, I've created this demo, which contains your latest solution to date. I've just added fields so we can see the list values on the page, rather than via console logs.

```js
(function($) {
  var attendance_radio = $(".input-radio-attendance");
  var diet_radio = $(".input-radio-diet");

  var accepted_array = [];
  var declined_array = [];

  var veg_array = [];
  var nonveg_array = [];

  /* sort accepted and declined into arrays */
  attendance_radio.on('change', function() {
    if (this.value === 'no') {
      $(".input-radio-diet[data-name='" + $(this).data("name") + "']").prop('checked', false);
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();

    if (checkedVal == "yes") {
      accepted_array.push(name);
      let index = declined_array.indexOf(name);
      if (index >= 0) {
        declined_array.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      declined_array.push(name);
      let index = 0;
      for (let theArray of [accepted_array, nonveg_array, veg_array]) {
        let index = theArray.indexOf(name);
        if (index >= 0) {
          theArray.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    var accepted_list = accepted_array.sort().join(",");
    var declined_list = declined_array.sort().join(",");

    $("#attending-list p").text(accepted_list);
    $("#declined-list p").text(declined_list);

    /* console.log("attending list: " + accepted_list);
    console.log("declined list: " + declined_list); */
  });

  /* get count of veg and non veg numbers */
  diet_radio.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();

    // only add to array if user is attending
    if (attendance_radio.val() == "yes") {
      if (checkedVal == "veg") {
        veg_array.push(name);
        let index = nonveg_array.indexOf(name);
        if (index >= 0) {
          nonveg_array.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } else {
        nonveg_array.push(name);
        let index = veg_array.indexOf(name);
        if (index >= 0) {
          veg_array.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    var veg_list = veg_array.sort().join(",");
    var nonveg_list = nonveg_array.sort().join(",");

    $("#veg-list p").text(veg_list);
    $("#nonveg-list p").text(nonveg_list);

    /*     console.log("veg list: " + veg_list);
        console.log("non veg list: " + nonveg_list); */
  });

  /* showing dietary fields if yes is selected */
  attendance_radio.each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var checkedVal = $this.val();

      if (checkedVal == "yes") {
        $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").addClass("d-flex");
        diet_radio.prop('required', true);
      } else {
        $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").removeClass("d-flex");
        diet_radio.prop('required', false);
      }
    });
  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.group,
.group__inner {
  display: flex;
}

.group {
  padding: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dietary {
  display: none;
}

.attendance {
  display: flex;
}

.d-flex {
  display: flex;
}


/* results */

.results {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 20px;
}

.results p {
  margin: 0;
}

.results span {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="group">

  <!------------->
  <!-- guest 1 -->
  <!------------->

  <div class="guest">
    <span class="guest__name">John</span>

    <div class="guest__options">
      <!-- attendace -->
      <div class="attendance">
        <span>Attending?</span>

        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-yes-0" type="radio" name="attendance-0" value="yes" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
          </div>

          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-no-0" type="radio" name="attendance-0" value="no" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="attending-no-0">No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- show dietary options when attendace is yes -->
      <div class="dietary">
        <span>Dietary preference</span>

        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-veg-0" type="radio" name="diet-0" value="veg" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="diet-veg-0">Vegetarian / Vegan</label>
          </div>

          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-nonveg-0" type="radio" name="diet-0" value="nonveg" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="diet-nonveg-0">Non-vegetarian</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!------------->
  <!-- guest 2 -->
  <!------------->

  <div class="guest">
    <span class="guest__name">Alex</span>

    <div class="guest__options">
      <!-- attendace -->
      <div class="attendance">
        <span>Attending?</span>

        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-yes-1" type="radio" name="attendance-1" value="yes" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
          </div>

          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-no-1" type="radio" name="attendance-1" value="no" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="attending-no-1">No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- show dietary options when attendace is yes -->
      <div class="dietary">
        <span>Dietary preference</span>

        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-veg-1" type="radio" name="diet-1" value="veg" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="diet-veg-1">Vegetarian / Vegan</label>
          </div>

          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-nonveg-1" type="radio" name="diet-1" value="nonveg" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="diet-nonveg-1">Non-vegetarian</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- see values -->
  <div class="results">
    <span id="attending-list"><strong>Attending:&nbsp;</strong>
      <p></p>
    </span>
    <span id="declined-list"><strong>Declined:&nbsp;</strong>
      <p></p>
    </span>
    <span id="veg-list"><strong>Veg:&nbsp;</strong>
      <p></p>
    </span>
    <span id="nonveg-list"><strong>Non veg:&nbsp;</strong>
      <p></p>
    </span>
  </div>

</div>
```

In the above demo, perform the following steps to recreate the issue:

1. For "*John*", click "yes" for attendance
2. ["*John*" is added to the "Attending" list]
3. For "*John*", click "Vegetarian / Vegan" for diet
4. ["*John*" is added to the "Veg" list]
5. For "*Alex*", click "yes" for attendance
6. ["*John*" and "*Alex*" now exist in the "Attending" list]
7. For "Alex", click "Non-vegetarian" for for diet
8. ["*Alex*" is added to the "Non-veg" list]
9. (Currently we have `attending`: "Alex, John", `declined`: "", `veg`: John and `non-veg`: "Alex")
10. Now, for "John", change his attendance to "no" but "John" still exists in the `veg` list

[image]

Comment: ``attendance_radio.val()`` is always ``yes`` because ``attendance_radio`` is a collection of elements and the ``val()`` method returns the value of the first element of this collection, which is ``yes``...

Comment: use instead ``$(this).closest(".guest").find(".input-radio-attendance:checked").val()``

Comment: Hi @biberman - I've replaced the above with `if ( $(this).closest(".guest").find(".input-radio-attendance:checked").val() == "yes" ) {}` but it showcases no changes? Also realised you removed your previous answer?

Comment: Yes, because it was wrong and i currently have no time to change it. But i think tomorrow i can check it again and then undelete it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply `sort()` your arrays before joining them:

```js
(function ($) {
  var attendance_radio = $(".input-radio-attendance");
  var diet_radio = $(".input-radio-diet");

  var accepted_array = [];
  var declined_array = [];

  var veg_array = [];
  var nonveg_array = [];

  /* sort accepted and declined into arrays */
  attendance_radio.on('change', function() {
    if (this.value === 'no') {
        $(".input-radio-diet[data-name='" + $(this).data("name") + "']").prop('checked', false);
    }
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();

    if (checkedVal == "yes") {
      accepted_array.push(name);
      let index = declined_array.indexOf(name);
      if (index >= 0) {
          declined_array.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } 
    else {
      declined_array.push(name);
      let index = 0;
      for (let theArray of [accepted_array, nonveg_array, veg_array]) {
          let index = theArray.indexOf(name);
          if (index >= 0) {
              theArray.splice(index, 1);
          }
      }
      console.log('veg list after not attending: ' + veg_array.sort().join(","));
      console.log('nonveg list after not attending: ' + nonveg_array.sort().join(","));
    }

    var accepted_list = accepted_array.sort().join(",");
    var declined_list = declined_array.sort().join(",");

    console.log("attending list: " + accepted_list);
    console.log("declined list: " + declined_list);
  });

  /* get count of veg and non veg numbers */
  diet_radio.on('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var name = $this.data("name");
    var checkedVal = $this.val();
  
    // only add to array if user is attending
    if ( attendance_radio.val() == "yes" ) {
      if (checkedVal == "veg") {
        veg_array.push(name);
        let index = nonveg_array.indexOf(name);
        if (index >= 0) {
            nonveg_array.splice(index, 1);
        }
      } 
      else {
        nonveg_array.push(name);
        let index = veg_array.indexOf(name);
        if (index >= 0) {
            veg_array.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
    }
  
    var veg_list = veg_array.sort().join(",");
    var nonveg_list = nonveg_array.sort().join(",");
  
    console.log("veg list: " + veg_list);
    console.log("non veg list: " + nonveg_list);
  });

  /* showing dietary fields if yes is selected */
  attendance_radio.each(function(index) {
    $(this).on("click", function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var checkedVal = $this.val();

      if( checkedVal == "yes" ) {
        $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").addClass("d-flex");
        diet_radio.prop('required',true);
      } 
      else {
        $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").removeClass("d-flex");
        diet_radio.prop('required',false);
      }
    });
  });
}) (jQuery);
```

```css
.group,
.group__inner{
  display: flex;
}

.group{
  width: 50%;
  padding: 30px;
  flex-direction: column;
}

span{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.dietary{
  display: none;
}

.attendance{
  display: flex;
}

.d-flex{
  display: flex;
}

.as-console-wrapper {
  left: auto!important;
  width: 50%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="group">

  <!------------->
  <!-- guest 1 -->
  <!------------->

  <div class="guest">
    <span class="guest__name">John</span>
    
    <div class="guest__options">
      <!-- attendace -->
      <div class="attendance">
        <span>Attending?</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-yes-0" type="radio" name="attendance-0" value="yes" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-no-0" type="radio" name="attendance-0" value="no" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="attending-no-0">No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- show dietary options when attendace is yes -->
      <div class="dietary">
        <span>Dietary preference</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-veg-0" type="radio" name="diet-0" value="veg" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="diet-veg-0">Vegetarian / Vegan</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-nonveg-0" type="radio" name="diet-0" value="nonveg" data-name="John" required />
            <label for="diet-nonveg-0">Non-vegetarian</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!------------->
  <!-- guest 2 -->
  <!------------->

  <div class="guest">
    <span class="guest__name">Alex</span>
    
    <div class="guest__options">
      <!-- attendace -->
      <div class="attendance">
        <span>Attending?</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-yes-1" type="radio" name="attendance-1" value="yes" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="attending-yes-0">Yes</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-attendance" id="attending-no-1" type="radio" name="attendance-1" value="no" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="attending-no-1">No</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <!-- show dietary options when attendace is yes -->
      <div class="dietary">
        <span>Dietary preference</span>
        
        <div class="group__inner">
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-veg-1" type="radio" name="diet-1" value="veg" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="diet-veg-1">Vegetarian / Vegan</label>
          </div>
          
          <div class="guest__options-group">
            <input class="input-radio-diet" id="diet-nonveg-1" type="radio" name="diet-1" value="nonveg" data-name="Alex" required />
            <label for="diet-nonveg-1">Non-vegetarian</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Applied two fixes:

1. I uncheck the veg/nonveg radio box if not attending is being checked
2. I remove the name from veg/nonveg if not attending is being checked

EDIT

Added additional logging for veg/nonveg after not attending. Sample test:

[image]

Comment: In your demo, if you select`yes` for attendance and non-veg option for both Alex and John, then change Johns attendance to `no` and then change Alex's diet option to veg (so it triggers the console log), you can still see Johns diet option in the veg array (when it should be removed as he's selected no for attendance)

Comment: I've edited my question to showcase a GIF of the steps to reproduce

Comment: @Freddy thanks for pointing that out, you were correct. I have applied a fix to it and fixed another issue. More information can be found in the edit to the answer. If the answer is correct now, then you might consider accepting it. If not, then please let me know what's missing and I'll look into it.

Comment: Hi Lajos, suffering the same issue with the edited code. In your demo, if you select `yes` for John and `veg`, then `yes` for Alex, then `non veg`, then it removes John from the `veg` list

Comment: Similarly, if you choose `yes` for Johns attendance and `no` for Alex, then it removes John from the attending list

Comment: @Freddy there was an error in the splicing indeed. Implemented a fix for that.

Comment: Hi Lajos, just letting you know I've seen your answer and, on quick glance, it seems to do the trick! Haven't had the time to look into it and test it properly (hopefully tomorrow), but once I do, and if all good, I will accept this answer.

Comment: @Freddy Thanks for letting me know. The tests succeeded for me, but of course your tests will be more important.

Comment: Hi Lajos, sorry for the delay. Finally got round to testing. I've just come across either a small bug, or a gap in my understanding. I've edited my question to showcase the details. Essentially a user isn't being removed from a list item when they change attendance

Comment: @Freddy when you click the non-attendance for John in your example, then the console only outputs the attendance. This might be confusing. I will try to reproduce your issue by outputting the veg list just efter nonattendance is clicked

Comment: @Freddy this seems to be a non-issue, basically we did not output the veg/nonveg list when we have chosen nonattendance, which caused confusion. At least, this was the result of my test. I have added further logging to make sure the output is not confusing. Can you test your same scenario now? That way we will be able to determine whether my results are correct and whether I have missed something. Thanks!

Comment: ah I see! I've created a function that updates all 4 arrays on radio button click which keeps all lists updated correctly at all times. But, your solution works for me and I'm grateful for your help! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function ($) {
    var attendance_radio = $(".input-radio-attendance");
    var diet_radio = $(".input-radio-diet");

    var accepted_array = [];
    var declined_array = [];

    var veg_array = [];
    var nonveg_array = [];

    /* sort accepted and declined into arrays */
    attendance_radio.on("change", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.data("name");
        var checkedVal = $this.val();

        if (checkedVal == "yes") {
            accepted_array.push(name);
            `if ($.inArray(name, declined_array) !== -1)`
                declined_array.splice($.inArray(name, declined_array), 1);
        } else {
            declined_array.push(name);
            if ($.inArray(name, accepted_array) !== -1)
                accepted_array.splice($.inArray(name, accepted_array), 1);
        }

        var accepted_list = accepted_array.join(",");
        var declined_list = declined_array.join(",");

        console.log("attending list: " + accepted_list);
        console.log("declined list: " + declined_list);
    });

    /* get count of veg and non veg numbers */
    diet_radio.on("change", function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var name = $this.data("name");
        var checkedVal = $this.val();

        // only add to array if user is attending
        if (attendance_radio.val() == "yes") {
            if (checkedVal == "veg") {
                veg_array.push(name);
                if ($.inArray(name, nonveg_array) !== -1)
                    nonveg_array.splice($.inArray(name, nonveg_array), 1);
            } else {`enter code here`
                nonveg_array.push(name);
                if ($.inArray(name, veg_array) !== -1)
                    veg_array.splice($.inArray(name, veg_array), 1);
            }
        }

        var veg_list = veg_array.join(",");
        var nonveg_list = nonveg_array.join(",");

        console.log("veg list: " + veg_list);
        console.log("non veg list: " + nonveg_list);
    });

    /* showing dietary fields if yes is selected */
    attendance_radio.each(function (index) {
        $(this).on("click", function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var checkedVal = $this.val();

            if (checkedVal == "yes") {
                $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").addClass("d-flex");
                diet_radio.prop("required", true);
            } else {
                $this.closest(".guest").find(".dietary").removeClass("d-flex");
                diet_radio.prop("required", false);
                
                let name = $this.data("name");
                
                if ($.inArray(name, veg_array) !== -1)
                    veg_array.splice($.inArray(name, veg_array), 1);
                if ($.inArray(name, nonveg_array) !== -1)
                    nonveg_array.splice($.inArray(name, nonveg_array), 1);
            }
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

First check if element exist in array before splicing else splice with start from -1 index element i.e. last element and it will empty array in your case

```
if ($.inArray(name, veg_array) !== -1)
```

For Second Point You need to add item removal code when user unselect the attendance

```
let name = $this.data("name");

if ($.inArray(name, veg_array) !== -1)
    veg_array.splice($.inArray(name, veg_array), 1);
if ($.inArray(name, nonveg_array) !== -1)
    nonveg_array.splice($.inArray(name, nonveg_array), 1);
```

For more information read out

1. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/hi10drasingh/pen/yLEdByv)
2. [jQuery.inArray](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray)
3. [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)